# Como filtrar linhas que possuem uma determinada string?

Tags: python, pandas

Sei que o comando `dados[dados.Value == 'disease']` apenas as linhas onde o valor da coluna "Value" é exatamente igual a string "disease", porém preciso selecionar todas as linhas da coluna "Value" que possuem a palavra "disease" (doença) em meio ao conjunto de carateres. É como se eu fosse fazer um `select * from df where value like "%disease%"`. Tem como fazer isso em Pandas ?

O resultado esperado é algo como:

```
                                     Entity          Relation                                 Value

2653297                         candy:heart  theriskofdisease  concept:disease:non_insulin_diabetes
2474203  physiologicalcondition:n2_diabetes        synonymfor  concept:disease:non_insulin_diabetes
```

Answer (score 5):

A solução é usar a função [.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html).

```
dados[dados.Value.str.contains("disease", regex=False)]
```

Vale ressaltar que esta função assume que a string passada é uma expressão regular, ou seja, possui o parâmetro `regex=True` como padrão.

Comment: Obrigado. Deu certo.